# Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, array

Se que esta pregunta se realizo muchisimas veces porque ya he buscado por todo el foro y otros foros mas, pero no cuentro la solucion ni el problema de raiz de lo que sucede.

Una breve explicación de lo que se debe realizar.

1- Se debe cargar datos de faturación en una tabla que se llama "factura_compra", a esos datos los traigo del formulario y los puede insertar bien.

2- Traer los datos de una tabla llamada "compra_detalle_temporal", como su nombre indica es la compra detallada pero es una tabla auxiliar que la utilizo para otras cosas aparte de esta funcionalidad.

3-Con los datos de la tabla temporal, debo insertarlos en una tabla llamada "factura_compra_detalle" donde se guardan practicamente los mismos datos pero esta es un historico.

4- (aún no lo programe porque quiero ir despacio) según la cantidad, el peso y la materia prima que este en la tabla, se debe actualizar el stock.

Para poder realizar esto, primero inserto los datos en la tabla de facturas. Luego hago un SELECT * FROM compra_detalle_temporal. Hasta ahi todo bien, (la conexion esta bien porque ya inserta datos y la query anterior tambien, porque hice que me imprima todos los datos en pantalla), hago un while donde recorre el array del SELEC * y dentro, hago el insert de los datos en factura_compra_detalle. Allí creo que esta el error, la linea del problema es la del while. Aún asi, hice la misma query de insert en la base de datos directamente y metio bien los datos. No se donde ni porque esta el problema. Dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
include("../system/conexion.php");
include("../materia_prima/update_mp.php");

//variables post
$id_bill = $_POST['id_bill'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$id_proveedor = $_POST['id_proveedor'];
$fecha = date("Y-m-d");

$consulta="INSERT INTO factura_compra (id_factura_compra,proveedor,fecha,total,total_iva) VALUE
($id_bill,$id_proveedor ,'$fecha', $total, ($total*0.21) + $total)";
$ejecucion=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);




//SACAR LOS DATOS DE compra_detalle_temporal Y METERLOS EN FACTURA_COMPRA_DETALLE
$consulta="SELECT * FROM compra_detalle_temporal";
$ejecucion=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

//el while es la linea del problema
while($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion)){
    $id_codigo_mp = $resultado['id_mp'];
    $unidades = $resultado['cantidad'];
    $peso_unitario = $resultado['peso_unitario'];
    $precio_unitario = $resultado['precio_unitario'];
    $id_proveedor = $resultado['id_proveedor '];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO factura_compra_detalle (id_factura,id_codigo_mp, unidades, peso_unitario, precio_unitario, id_proveedor, fecha) VALUE
    ($id_bill,$id_codigo_mp, $unidades,$peso_unitario,$precio_unitario,$id_proveedor, '$fecha')";
    $ejecucion=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
   
}
```

?>

Comment: De por sí es una mala práctica meter consultas dentro de consultas y encima dentro de bucles. Hay mil formas de simplificar esto, pero sería motivo de otro debate... Por otra parte, te aconsejo que controles tu código, es tu deber como programador. Para este caso concreto, empieza controlando por donde **crees** que falla, si es el  INSERT dentro del `while` entonces pon un `if ($ejecucion=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) { echo "No hubo error insertando: $consulta"; } else { echo "ERROR en la consulta: $consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion); }`

Comment: ADVIERTO que ese es un control de error muy básico, al menos para saber por qué falla tu código. Como ya dije, hay que optimizar muchas cosas, faltarían más controles, hay problema de seguridad, etc. Por ejemplo, en fase de producción del código deberás evitar mostrar mensajes de error internos, deberás usar consultas preparadas, deberás pensar en usar transacciones para insertar datos masivos, etc. OTRA cosa: evita llamar igual dos variables que podrían entrecruzarse, en el caso de `$ejecucion`, la nombras igual dentro del bucle, no sé exactamente lo que eso podría provocar.

Comment: Lo del `if` que puse más arriba deberías hacerlo con todas tus consultas, debes controlar **todo tu código**, de forma que cuando ocurra un error sepas lo que tienes que hacer, si mostrar un mensaje de error, si indicar al usuario lo que hizo mal para que lo corrija, etc. Un programa sin control de errores no es un programa acabado, por lo que el control de errores en los programas es fundamental. Aquí  tú programas de forma ingenua, creyendo que siempre todo irá bien. No, **debes pensar que cualquier cosa podría ir mal** y que tu deber como programador es responder cuando algo salga mal.

Comment: @A.Cedano, claro, obviamente voy a hacer el control de errores y demas, yo programo siempre desde lo simple a lo complejo. Ahora cambie como dijiste el nombre del segundo ejecucion y no muestra error pero de 5 registros que tengo en la temporal, solo agrega 1

Comment: Es que, realmente no necesitas el `SELECT` y luego leer esos datos para hacer el `INSERT`... Tú puedes **hacer un INSERT basado en un SELECT** (aquí hablo a nivel de SQL), simplificando así el código. Por otra parte, el que unos registros no sean insertados puede deberse a varios motivos, por tanto, tu tarea como programador es prever que una inserción puede fallar por A, por B o por C y que en esos casos debes controlar también los fallos y tener una respuesta adecuada cuando ocurran.

Comment: Independientemente de que optimices más adelante, si en todas tus lecturas pones un `if` vas a saber por qué sólo insertan algunos registros y otros no. ¿Será por clave duplicada, será porque algún dato viola alguna restricción, etc? La forma de saber si un código falla es controlando los errores y/o atando corto al código, preguntando por todo aquello que podría fallar o cuando sea posible, usando bloques `try ... catch` . El control de errores no se deja para último, porque lo que ocurre es que pierdes más tiempo depurando un programa escrito de manera ingenua.